# I have a problem while executing a '.exe' file in git bash

Tags: git-bash, git-for-windows

It doesn't execute the command when I type it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD1dp.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the .exe file, that you want to execute, is in the current directory, you have to type

```
./command
```

Look for documentation for the environment variable `PATH` if you do not want to type `./` in front of your command.

Comment: The current directory (`.`) is intentionally not present in `$PATH` for security reasons. Do not add it!

Comment: Yes, do not add ```.``` to ```PATH```. But you can move the command to a directory contained in ```$PATH``` or add a new directory (where you want to place the command) to ```PATH```.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing preventing execution of `.exe` files in msys-git/git-for-windows, which you seem to be using.

Your program `oop1`does not seem to output anything.